# What is better? For-loops or generator expressions (in cases like this)

Tags: python

Which version of this code is better?

Ver 1.

```
a = 0
for i in xrange( 1000 ):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        a += i
print a
```

Ver 2.

```
from operator import add
print reduce( add,
              ( i for i in xrange( 1000 )
                if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0 ) )
```

Things I like about version one is that it is more readable, but it creates requires a variable. If you had to choose, which one would you argue is better?

Comment: Version 3: Use the `sum()` function with the generator used in version 2.

Comment: is `list descriptor` a correct name for that ? Should not be `for-loops` vs `generator comprehensions` ?

Comment: @joaquin Yes, it should (and is now). Descriptors are [something entirely different](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second version can (and should) be written using `sum` instead of `reduce(add,...)`, which is somewhat more readable:

```
sum(i for i in xrange( 1000 ) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0)
```

That is the version that I'd prefer as far as implementations of this particular algorithm go because it's more declarative than a loop and just reads nicer in my opinion. (It's also faster though that's less of a concern).

However it should be noted that for summing all numbers up to n that divisible by 3 or 5, [there's actually a better algorithm than going over all those numbers and summing them](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/280/128).

Comment: On testing, the generator version is not faster than a simple `for` loop. Do you have a reference / benchmarking to support your claim?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `reduce`, it is removed python 3.

```
kracekumar@python-lover:~$ python -m timeit 'sum(i for i in xrange(1000) if i%3 ==0 or i%5==0) '
1000 loops, best of 3: 232 usec per loop

kracekumar@python-lover:~$ python -m timeit 'sum([i for i in xrange(1000) if i%3 ==0 or i%5==0]) '

10000 loops, best of 3: 177 usec per loop
```

First method uses `generators` second one uses `list comprehensions`.

You can use both but `generators` will occupy less memory.

```
In [28]: g = (i for i in xrange(1000) if i%3 ==0 or i%5==0)

In [29]: l = [i for i in xrange(1000) if i%3 ==0 or i%5==0]

In [30]: import sys

In [31]: sys.getsizeof(l)
Out[31]: 2136

In [32]: sys.getsizeof(g)
Out[32]: 36
```

It is advised to use generators, here is a beautiful tutorial about [generators](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/).

Comment: `reduce` isn't removed in Python 3, just moved (into the functools module).