# Project Euler #1: Sum of Multiples of 3 and 5 below 1000

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge

```
def prob_1():
    sum_mult=[]  #Create an empty list which will take sum of multiples of 3 and 5
    check_sum=0
    for i in range(1,1000): #Take numbers till 1000
    #if(i)
        if( (i%3)==0 or (i%5)==0 ): #divisor condition
            sum_mult.append(i)

    return sum(sum_mult)    #return sum of list
```

I am just starting out my journey as a programmer, here is my code and I would love to see any critical feedback and other alternative solutions maybe using some clever hack of using lambda function's etc.

Comment: To make this program really fast, look at any other review on this site that is also about Project Euler #1. The programming language doesn't matter, it's basically the same in all languages.

Comment: I'm especially thinking about https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/280, which is really fast.

Comment: Is `i % 35` really the condition you would like to check?

Answer (score 8):

I expect you made a typo.  You don't want `(i%35)==0`, you want `(i%5)==0`.

---

The [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide for Python requires 1 space before and after operators, and after commas.  Use PyLint or equivalent tool to ensure you follow all of the PEP-8 guidelines.

---

`check_sum` is unused, and can be omitted.

---

The brackets around the `if( ... ):` condition are unnecessary.  This is Python, not C, C++ or Java:

```
    if (i % 3) == 0 or (i % 5) == 0: #divisor condition
```

---

There is no need to create a list just to add up all the numbers after the fact.  You are only using each value once, so you could simply add the numbers up as you find them:

```
def prob_1():

    sum_of_multiples = 0

    for i in range(1, 1000):  # Take numbers up to but not including 1000
        if (i % 3) == 0 or (i % 5) == 0: #divisor condition
            sum_of_multiples += i

    return sum_of_multiples
```

---

You should add `"""doc_strings"""` to your functions:

```
def prob_1():
    """
    Compute the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

    Returns:
        The sum of the multiples of 3 or 5, below 1000.
    """

    sum_of_multiples = 0

    for i in range(1, 1000):  # Take numbers up to but not including 1000
        if (i % 3) == 0 or (i % 5) == 0: #divisor condition
            sum_of_multiples += i

    return sum_of_multiples
```

---

You can use <s>list comprehension</s> a generator expression (thanks @Graipher) and the `sum(...)` function to compute the result, without ever creating the list in memory:

```
def prob_1():
    """
    Compute the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

    Returns:
        The sum of the multiples of 3 or 5, below 1000.
    """

    return sum(i for i in range(1000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0)
```

---

You can also solve this problem by hand with a pen, a sheet of paper, a calculator and about 1 minute of your time.  A program is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: You eventually arrive at it, but I'd also add that it is not common to parenthesize the modulo operator (or most other infix operators) like that. `i % 3 == 0` is preferred to `(i % 3) == 0`.

Comment: Should be `and` instead of `or`, I think. OP wants multiple of 3 **and** 5. So, `3,6,9,12,15,...` intersects `5,10,15,20,...`

Comment: @Sigur yeah you can take two sets and apply union also.