# Merge two strictly increasing sequences, without duplicates

Tags: performance, swift, iterator

This work is motivated by [Sum of natural numbers below threshold](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/279135/sum-of-natural-numbers-below-threshold), where several Swift solutions to [Project Euler #1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1) (with arbitrary upper bound) are provided.

One way to think of it is to

- start with two sequences (the multiples of 3 and the multiples of 5),
- merge these two sequences into a new sequence, in increasing order, without duplicates,
- finally add all elements of the merge sequence.

This question is about reviewing a generic solution for the second part:

> Given two sequences (whose elements are strictly increasing), create a new “merged” sequence containing the elements of both, in increasing order, without duplicates.

With that `increasingMerge()` function, the solution to the above problem could be computed as

```swift
let upperBound = 10_000
print(increasingMerge(of: stride(from: 3, to: upperBound, by: 3),
                      and: stride(from: 5, to: upperBound, by: 5))
    .reduce(0, +))
```

This is surely not the most efficient way to solve Project Euler #1 (which in fact can be solved in [O(1) time and O(1) space](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/280/35991)), but that is not the goal. The goal is to provide universally applicable function to merge two increasing sequences.

There seems to be no such function in [Swift Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Chain.md). The overall approach with a global function, which returns an instance of `IncreasingMergeSequence` (conforming to the `Sequence` protocol), is inspired by [Chain.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/Algorithms/Chain.swift). The code uses O(1) additional space.

Any and all feedback is welcome (coding style, naming, efficiency, access control, ...)

```swift
public struct IncreasingMergeSequence<Base1: Sequence, Base2: Sequence>: Sequence
    where Base1.Element == Base2.Element, Base1.Element: Comparable
{
    public typealias Element = Base1.Element // The common element type
    
    private let base1: Base1
    private let base2: Base2

    fileprivate init(base1: Base1, base2: Base2) {
        self.base1 = base1
        self.base2 = base2
    }
    
    public struct IncreasingMergeIterator: IteratorProtocol {
        private var iterator1: Base1.Iterator
        private var iterator2: Base2.Iterator

        private var elem1: Element? = nil
        private var elem2: Element? = nil
        
        fileprivate init(iterator1: Base1.Iterator, iterator2: Base2.Iterator) {
            self.iterator1 = iterator1
            self.iterator2 = iterator2
            elem1 = self.iterator1.next()
            elem2 = self.iterator2.next()
        }
        
        public mutating func next() -> Element? {
            switch (elem1, elem2) {
            case (let x?, let y?):
                if x < y {
                    elem1 = iterator1.next()
                    return x
                } else if y < x {
                    elem2 = iterator2.next()
                    return y
                } else {
                    elem1 = iterator1.next()
                    elem2 = iterator2.next()
                    return x
                }
            case (let x?, nil):
                elem1 = iterator1.next()
                return x
            case (nil, let y?):
                elem2 = iterator2.next()
                return y
            case (nil, nil):
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

    public func makeIterator() -> IncreasingMergeIterator {
        IncreasingMergeIterator(iterator1: base1.makeIterator(), iterator2: base2.makeIterator())
     }
}

/// Returns a new sequence containing the elements of two sequences, in increasing order,
/// without duplicates.
/// - Attention: It is assumed that the elements of both sequences are in strictly increasing order.
/// - Parameters:
///   - s1: The first sequence.
///   - s2: The second sequence.
/// - Returns: A sequence of the elements of `s1` and `s2`, in increasing order, without duplicates.

public func increasingMerge<S1, S2>(of s1: S1, and s2: S2) -> IncreasingMergeSequence<S1, S2> {
    return IncreasingMergeSequence(base1: s1, base2: s2)
}
```

Comment: Not gonna write up a full answer because I think this is merely personal taste, but I would replace that `if/else if/else` ladder with `case (let x?, let y?) where x < y`, `case (let x?, let y?) where x > y`, and `case (let x?, let y?)`

Comment: @Alexander: Yes, I had thought about it, and my personal tasted decided against it :) I did not like the repetition of `(let x?, let y?)` in three cases.

Comment: Pattern matching is pretty expensive. On TIO, optional binding gives a 22% speed gain. Here it is on TIO: [original](https://cutt.ly/RX0WCNN) 9ms, vs 7ms for [the modified version](https://cutt.ly/1X0WmV0)). Mind you, TIO is still using Swift 4. The difference is more pronounced on [SwiftFiddle](https://swiftfiddle.com/iicpsrrgkrbengp4n7nohzmrwa) which uses Swift 5.6.2, but code optimizations are most certainly off. Readability and extensibility are sacrificed.

Comment: Bearing in mind that this could potentially be included in the Swift algorithms module, is there a good reason to avoid inlining? I'd be curious to see if forcing inlining with @_transparent would have as much of a speed boost on your machine as on [SwiftFiddle](https://swiftfiddle.com/bvrf5qw4trcqvif3be3l4r5ljy)

Comment: @ielyamani: I do not have much knowledge about possible (dis)advantages of inlining code from external modules, and I haven't made myself familiar with attributes like `@usableFromInline` or `@_transparent`, therefore I cannot say much about it.